# how can i retrieve list of members from a given muc room id in xmpp?

Tags: xmpp, strophe

```
<iq from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda' id='kl2fax27' to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit' type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
</iq>
```

I have tried above code, it gives only nicknames, I want jid's of all members of the group to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the room to present jabber id's to anyone. By default, all cases I have seen, it's only set to mods. You can set this as a default on the server in most cases. Or, using an app such as PSI, you can join the conference as an admin and set it there, or when setting up a room through script add the following to your form data when submitting your room to the server when creating the room:

```
iq.c('field', { 'var': 'muc#roomconfig_whois' }).c('value').t('anyone');
```

Comment: Thanks mark, After setting muc#roomconfig_whois to anyone, i tried below code, but its showing error:<not-authorized xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>                                                               $iq('to':'roomid@chat.service.com','from':'barejid@service.com').c('query',{'xmlns':'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'}).c('item',{'affiliation':'member'});

Comment: That appears to be a different issue. Not clear on what you are trying to accomplish with that. When running the disco#items in your original question, do you now get the jids you were looking for?

Comment: the above code which i wrote in comment returns all jids of members in a group to admin(if xmlns:jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin}), but not for member, my task is, a member should be able to retrieve all jids in group which he has joined.